# Real time chat - is it possible to see messages from it again

Tags: server, isp

I have a theoretical question. If you went on a website which provides real time chat service, and only login information it requires is a username of your choice, and the website adress was https, and after you exit the chat you can never see your previous chats, even if you log in again with the same username, can your ISP find which messages you have sent, and which were sent to you? I'm no tech expert, but I suppose if you send some data, for example, messages, using Internet access and data plan provided from your ISP, that they can eventually see those messages, because bytes necessery to make them go through their servers or I don't know how, that's how I understand it. Anyway, is there a way for autorities to decrypt those messages? And does that way require only information they could get from ISP, or would they need to contact the server and see if they store messages. I'm really interested in computers and security, so I would like to know how this works. Sorry for not being well educated about it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think there's far too many variables in this to answer it with anything other than a very definite maybe.

In general, the way to be safe is to assume that for any way you would want the answer to be yes, the answer is no, and any way you want the answer to be no, it's yes.

Comment: it depends on the chat. if they are using E2E, then probably no (unless the E2E is weak/defective), otherwise probably yes (they can log the clear traffic)